# How can I connect different class instances based on their ids?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I have the two following classes:

```
class Position(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.price = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"id: {self.id}, product: {self.product.name}, quantity: {self.quantity}"


class Sale(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position)
    total_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Total sales price: ${self.total_price}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sales:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.transaction_id == '':
            self.transaction_id = generate_code()
        if self.created is None:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_position(self):
        return self.positions.all()
```

How can I relate each position instance with its related sale instance?

I've tried implementing this method:

```
def get_sales_id(self):
        sale_obj = self.sale_set.first()
        return sale_obj.id
```

but in this case I will always get the first id of a determined position occurrence.

Exaple:
pos1: id 1,  product, quanity,  price ...
pos2: id 2, product, quantity, price ...

sale1: pos 1, pos 2 ...
sale2: pos 1, pos3 ...

When I try to merge these, based on the sale id, I get:

pos1: id 1, ... , sale_id 1
pos1: id 1, ... , sale_id 1 <= when it should be 2!

I've tried to set up this filter, but I just can't wrap my head around how to make it work:

```
def get_id(self):
        related_sale_obj = Sale.objects.filter(positions = self)
        
        #related_id = related_obj.id
        #sales_id_prefetched = self.sale_set.only('Position').explain()
        return related_sale_obj
```

If you have any idea on how I could fix this, it'd be much appreciated.
Have a nice day

Comment: If it's new project  and you are allowed to remove existing data, I think best option would be to add ForeignKey on Position to Sale and remove M2M on Sale. This way you can get Sale instance from Position by field name, and all Sale positions using position_set

Comment: I see. I thought about it as well, however I wanted to keep a ManyToMany relationship between Sale and Position, however if I can't figure it out I will resort to using ForeignKey.  Thank you very much